# f# Clone Record data

Tags: f#, f#-data

I'm writing a script to move data from one database server to another. One table at a time is good for me. I've removed all the foreign keys and such.

I'm following this example.

http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/low-risk-ways-to-use-fsharp-at-work-4/#sql-etl

The issue is that I don't want to transform the data, I just want to copy it. But I have a lot of tables and each table has a lot of columns. What is an easy way to map from one record to another, without mapping each individual field?

Comment: what database? MS-SQL for example has some inbuilt stuff (tasks) for exactly this kind of bulk-data insert

Comment: aside from this there is no *nice* way when you have different record-types - you can use reflection and stuff but this is horrible slow and you will never be happy

Comment: It's just a one time thing. I was looking for sql built stuff but I wasn't getting great hits.

Comment: If you are using SQL server take a look at this snippet: http://fssnip.net/tM

Comment: That's really cool! I didn't see this before either. However, I can't do a full database stomp. But I'll keep looking at this script to see if I can target specific tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can slightly modify the script quoted by @Petr to copy specified tables as opposed to all of them. Please see an example of doing this below.

```
// Start of modifications here

// Create an array of objects in this case tables to copy
let tablesToCopy = 
    sourceDatabase.Tables 
    |> Seq.cast<Table> // Convert TableCollection to seq<Table> so can use Seq functions
    |> Seq.filter (fun table -> [| "DimTime"; "DimCategory" |] |> Seq.exists (fun tableName -> tableName = table.Name)) 
    |> Seq.toArray // Materialise to an Array so it can be consumed by an ArrayList constructor and assigned to the ObjectList property

let transferDatabase = 
    Transfer(sourceDatabase, 
        CopyAllObjects = false, // Set to false
        CopyAllSchemas = true, 
        CopyAllUserDefinedDataTypes = true, 
        CopyAllTables = false, // Set to false
        ObjectList = System.Collections.ArrayList(tablesToCopy), // Include a list of objects to copy - uses old style ArrayList
        CopyData = true, 
        CopyAllStoredProcedures = true,
        DestinationServer = destServer.Name,
        DestinationDatabase = destDatabase.Name)

// End of modifications here
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! I will warn anyone else, that this will pull all foreign keyed tables too. So tables that were foreign keyed and I didn't specify in the list, it threw an error unless I specified them.

Comment: I can't get it to copy keys and constraints. CopyAllSchemas tries to copy things that don't belong to the database. I set CopySchema = true, but it still doesn't copy. I went through all the attributes in intellisense that I could. But I don't know where to go for official documentation on this.

Comment: Have you tried using the Options property. For example the following works for me when copying Primary Keys and Unique Constraints: transferDatabase.Options.DriAllKeys <- true. You can find more on this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scriptingoptions_properties.aspx).